# Is it a bad idea to copy project folders for backup? Add existing items instead?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, backup

I'm learning C# (self-teaching first real programming language other than VBA).

Consistently, my text book asks me to create new project and add a bunch of existing items from an old project when I don't want to mess up my existing project. This seems to be their way of creating a backup. They never really said not to just copy folders so I've been doing that and it works fine.

The IDE doesn't allow you to save a whole project with a new name (i.e. Save As: "BACKUP Of projectName") so instead I close the IDE and just copy the folder. It's been a great time saver rather than following their laborious instructions but I fear that I'm teaching myself a bad habit. Please tell me my fears are unfounded.

Comment: I do it often :-) Even at work. And we have a VCS (Version Control System)... but copying a folder locally is often faster than using the VCS (and not all the VCS support "personal" branching)

Comment: The alternative is using a VCS (version control system... git, mercurial, subversion) locally... But if you want to be able to work with multiple versions of the program at the same time, this only adds complexity... still I consider a VCS for backup purpose a good idea

Comment: @Methodician It sounds to me like this is a good time to learn about a VCS, contrary to what the previous poster xanatos says. On a VCS you'd create a fork of the project you want to use and then work on the fork, following whichever VCS you choose to use workflow. VCS systems offer a great deal of power and flexibility and it's a very good habit to learn one. There are many out there, I personally use GIT, they offer full versioning etc... They really aren't over kill and aren't overly complex once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @DanielLane I do think that it is always a good time to learn a VCS :-) I normally prefer Mercurial because it is simpler to use (I don't like the two-phase commit, because I have to use Subversion and TFS at work, so my mind is mono-phase commited), and at least until some years ago Mercurial was better integrated with Windows than Git... But now it has changed, with Microsoft supporting git.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, I worded my last comment too strongly. Anyway with regards to versioning systems, it's very much a matter of preference, they're all more or less on par anyways. Methodician - version control, it's the future! Pick one, learn it and stick with it! =)

Comment: Thanks guys! Apparently I wasn't getting notified about comments (maybe I unchecked a box when posting) so I've still been laboring over the potential ramifications of my new habit. I'm doing it more and more since I like to back up - and came back to see why I hadn't gotten an answer but there it was! Maybe it would have helped if one of you posted this as an answer rather than comment, since it's exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes along seeking answers - note that the question has been well answered via discussion in the comments.

It sounds like my practice won't blow anything up but there's a better way: a "Version Control System" or "VCS". I'm going to have to do a little research and pick one before my semi-bad habit gets too ingrained.

Thanks @xantos and @DanielLane!